# Final static field of Integer[] type can be changed

Tags: java, android, constants, final

I have a Constants class, that has a static final field. I found out, that I can rewrite this field.

```
public static final Integer[] THUMBS = {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two};
```

In my code I make

```
mThumbIdsForAdapter = Constants.THUMBS;
```

And then

```
mThumbIdsForAdapter[position] = mThumbIdsBlue[position];
```

After it my Constants.THUMBS contains element mThumbIdsBlue[position]...

How is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: The reference to the array is static and final while the values contained inside are not.

Comment: Only the array reference is immutable. Java does **not** support arrays where the *content* is immutable. If you want that, you have to look into using Lists, and corresponding helper methods such as Collections.unmodifiableList(someList) In other words: when you use an array type, it is always possible to change individual slots via a simply assignment.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about it(